# URL with multiple parameters, incorrect syntax error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am integrating with a system that creates part of a URL and I supply part of the URL.

I supply this:

```
http://myServer/gis/default.aspx?MAP_NAME=myMap
```

The system supplies this:

```
?type=mrolls&rolls='123','456'
```

(the "rolls" change depending on what the user chooses in the system)

so, my URL ends up looking like this:

```
http://myServer/gis/default.aspx?MAP_NAME=myMap?type=mrolls&rolls='123','456'
```

I need to get the rolls but when I try this in VB.Net:

```
Dim URL_ROLL As String = Request.QueryString("rolls")
```

I get an incorrect syntax error.
I think it's a combination of the 2nd question mark and the single quotes.
When the system is only passing one roll, it works, I can get the rolls from the URL

which looks like this:

```
http://myServer/gis/default.aspx?MAP_NAME=myMap?type=roll&roll=123
```

I asked them to change the format of the system's URL but they can't change it without affecting the rest of their users.

Can anyone give me some ideas on how to get the rolls from the URL with single quotes?

Comment: What do you mean a syntax error?  you can't get one at compile time based on the input data, unless you are declaring your test data wrong.  Post that up too.

Comment: Is the part of the code that prepares and posts the final url completely closed?  Could you append `&MAP_NAME=myMap` to the end somehow after the 3rd-party code has run?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I can't append &MAP_NAME=myMap to the end, I'm limited by the system I'm integrating with. the syntax error is that it turns my single quotes into this (the single quotes become special characters, question marks in diamonds):    �724560�,�745320�

Answer (score 0):

OK, I believe I've fixed my problem. 
I used a regular expression to remove anything in the querystring that wasn't a number or a comma.
Thanks again for taking time to make your comments, it made me look at the problem from a different angle.